# "Max Steel" episode in which Max got stuck in a cave blocked by ice

Tags: episode-identification, max-steel

I remember watching a *Max Steel* (2000) episode on Cartoon Network. Here are the details I remember:

- Max's girlfriend had a crush on a guy. That guy was either new in town or they were in his town or everyone was in a tourist place.
- There was this ice skating or boarding (or, some other ice game) competition between Max and that guy.
- Weather went harsh or it was criminal action that Max, that guy and Max's girlfriend got stuck inside a cave having its entrance blocked by ice.
- It wasn't a big deal for Max, but he couldn't do anything special because of that guy there.
- They tried to remove the ice until the oxygen ran out of the place and that guy fainted.
- Then, Max Steel said "Going Turbo" (I could have phrased it the other way, but the dialogue is one of my favorite) and punched his way out within seconds.

Comment: You should link the a page for the particular version of Max Steel it was.

Comment: @Axelrod Sorry, I didn't know that they launched a new TV series. I am talking about old 2000 series.

Comment: I knew. That show was great to watch in the morning, before school.

Comment: @Axelrod It was an evening show in my country...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for Season 3, Episode 28: [Survival Instinct](http://www.sidereel.com/Max_Steel/season-3/episode-2)

> While in the Alps snowboarding, Team Steel has a dangerous run-in with
>   Ethan Raptor, leader of a rival Extreme Sports Team called Team Raptor
>   (which includes athlete Tripp Thompson and manager Carlie Hoffman.)

Comment: Your link isn't working.

Comment: @SS-3 Hopefully this one works.